# How to make turn server fast

Tags: django, webrtc

I've been working on a personal project for 2 months and I am trying to build a Video conferencing web application using django and WebRTC.

I am facing an issue: I am using several STUN/TURN servers but the TURN server is too slow and doesn't provide a good user experience.

I am using some public TURN servers. If I only use STUN servers then it only works in some specific network conditions.

The servers that I am using are:

```
    let iceConfiguration = {
    "iceServers":
        [
            // { url :'stun4.l.google.com:19302'},
            // { url: 'stunserver.org:3478'},
            { url: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' },
            { url: 'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302' },
            { url: 'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302' },
            { url: 'stun:stun3.l.google.com:19302' },
            {
                url: 'turn:numb.viagenie.ca',
                credential: 'muazkh',
                username: 'webrtc@live.com'
            },
            {
                url: 'turn:relay.backups.cz',
                credential: 'webrtc',
                username: 'webrtc'
            },
            {
                url: 'turn:relay.backups.cz?transport=tcp',
                credential: 'webrtc',
                username: 'webrtc'
            },
            {
                url: 'turn:192.158.29.39:3478?transport=udp',
                credential: 'JZEOEt2V3Qb0y27GRntt2u2PAYA=',
                username: '28224511:1379330808'
            },
            {
                url: 'turn:192.158.29.39:3478?transport=tcp',
                credential: 'JZEOEt2V3Qb0y27GRntt2u2PAYA=',
                username: '28224511:1379330808'
            },
            {
                url: 'turn:turn.bistri.com:80',
                credential: 'homeo',
                username: 'homeo'
             },
             {
                url: 'turn:turn.anyfirewall.com:443?transport=tcp',
                credential: 'webrtc',
                username: 'webrtc'
            }
        ]
    };
```

And my whole code is here https://github.com/nikhilkotiya/Microsoft-Teams/tree/newbranch

Please help me out for this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use overcrowded public TURN servers then, use your own TURN server, or a paid-for commercial one…

Comment: is there any way to make personal turn server on windows?@deceze

Comment: Probably, but frankly I wouldn't bother, unless you have time on your hands to set it up and maintain it or want to run this with absolutely zero cost somehow. I'd use the servers of Twilio, which will cost you mere cents a month for small services. If your service gets big enough so that it becomes more expensive, it's almost certainly a better option to use such commercial services instead of trying to maintain an adequately scaling server-fleet of TURN servers yourself.

Comment: You won't need a fleet, a single instance of coturn can serve thousands of clients.  It's easy to setup, too, although I wouldn't recommend using Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You need an aws ec2 instance, then follow this tutorial installing coturn in the instance:
https://gabrieltanner.org/blog/turn-server
Ps. Be sure to select your country in aws, otherwise you will get pretty bad latency, and very laggy calls
Pps. Test your server here
https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/
Before testing it in app